# Android ActionBar not showing icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have seen this question asked many times, however, none of those solutions have helped me. My problem is that I have an ActionBar menu and I want its items to always be displayed on the ActionBar instead of the drop down menu.

I have tried actions suchs as "ifRoom", "always", etc. and they still show only with text on the drop down menu.

Menu: devotional_fragment_actions.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_previous"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
        android:title="@string/previous_action"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_go_to_today"
        android:title="@string/date_action"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_next"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:title="@string/next_action"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

On my fragment I have:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // action bar
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.devotional_fragment_actions, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle item selection of action bar
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            showDatePickerDialog();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The menu works fine but is not displaying as I want it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each item use `android` namespace instead of `app`. You can even remove this namespace declaration `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Try set it like in code below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_previous"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
        android:title="@string/previous_action"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: I've tried that and it says the following 'Should use app:showAsAction with appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"'

Comment: I'm using such declaration in all of my apps and didn't get anything like that.

Comment: Try to leave as it was in your variant and just add android:showAsAction="always", so you will have them both.

Comment: I just tried that but it still shows the same error. What I don't understand is that this is how the official Android guide does it and it doesn't work for me. I have used the ActionBAr before and never had this problem

Comment: Did you leave xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in you xml ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It did not make a difference

Comment: Did you got any error while running code or it just didn't work ?

Comment: Try to do smth with your appcompat library

Comment: You are right, it does work. I'm using AndroidStudio and it was underlining it as an error, but the app runs. So using xlmns:android is the solution and there is no need to even write xlmns:app. Strange since that's what I saw [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). Thank you!

Comment: You may want to edit it to only use xmlns:android. Answer accepted!